# jQuery Only Works When Logged into WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress

For some reason, my jQuery scripts only seem to load when I am logged into WordPress. Here is the page:
http://www.mcfaddengavender.net/newmg/

As you can see, the images are not "sliding" in. However, if I login and return to the homepage, things work fine. Here is the code I'm using to run jQuery in the Functions.php:

```
//jQuery - Use Google CDN instead of WP jQuery
function my_scripts_method() {
if (!is_admin()) { 
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery',     'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
 }
}

add_action('init', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Any ideas on what would cause such a weird issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hooking in the wrong place  use

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

rather than 'init'